# Django Rest Framework serializer validator always empty

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to print out the list of validators in django rest framework, however when I print it out it seem like it is always empty.

Here is a part of the code

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer


    def create(self, request):

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        # this always return []
        print serializer.validators
```

This is counterintuitive because when I tested invalid data in `request.data` , the code clearly runs the validator since `is_valid()` return error as the [documentation](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py) indicates. Therefore it doesn't make sense that I can observe the validator taking effect but can't print it out. Can someone point out what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a `validators` attribute. Did you try `get_validators()`? Also, I usually find what I need to know from reading the source. https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1297

Comment: I think `validators` are in this line `for validator in self.validators:` in [line 488](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py), I tried `get_validators` after you mentioned it, and still got `[]` when I print it out, which is weird because I can see that when I pass invalid data in it will return errors

Comment: Yes, but this is a `Field` objects, not a `Serializer` object.

Comment: Basic serializer inherits Field in `class BaseSerializer(Field):` [line 58](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py) , I also checked the serializer class, it seems like there is no validator besides the one inherited from Field?

Answer (score 3):

**Why `serializer.validators` returns `[]` in your case?**

This is happening because you have not passed a `validators` arguments to the serializer when creating an instance of the serializer. Had you passed the `validators` argument, then `serializer._validators` would be set to that value. Then, if you check `serializer.validators`, it would give you the list of validators passed.

For Example:

```
In [1]: serializer = SomeSerializer(data=some_data, validators=[validator1, validator2])

In [2]: serializer.validators
Out [2]: [validator1, validator2] # gives the list of validators
```

By default, `[]` is returned if no validators is passed when accessing `serializer.validators`.

**Source code for reference:**

Now, `BaseSerializer` inherits from `Field`  class which calls its `__init__()`.

```
class BaseSerializer(Field):

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
        ...
        super(BaseSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Here, `default_validators` is an empty list `[]`.

```
class Field(object):

    default_validators = [] # an empty list by default
    default_empty_html = empty
    initial = None

    def __init__(self, read_only=False, write_only=False,
                 required=None, default=empty, initial=empty, source=None,
                 label=None, help_text=None, style=None,
                 error_messages=None, validators=None, allow_null=False):

        ...

        # Here, it checks if validators argument was passed when creating the serializer instance
        # If you have passed, then `.validators` will be set to that value.
        if validators is not None:
            self.validators = validators[:]

        ...

    @property
    def validators(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_validators'): 
            # This will be executed as there was no validators passed in kwargs
            self._validators = self.get_validators()
        return self._validators

    @validators.setter
    def validators(self, validators):
        self._validators = validators


    def get_validators(self):
        return self.default_validators[:] # returns empty list
```

**Why your code shows error for invalid data then?**

This is because field-level validators are causing that error. Your serializer-level validators is `[]` but there are some field-level validators which are raising error for invalid data.

To see field-level validators, you can do `print repr(serializer)`.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/

> ### Validation in REST framework
>
> Validation in Django REST framework serializers is handled a little
>   differently to how validation works in Django's ModelForm class.
>
> With ModelForm the validation is performed partially on the form, and
>   partially on the model instance. With REST framework the validation is
>   performed entirely on the serializer class. This is advantageous for
>   the following reasons:
>
> - It introduces a proper separation of concerns, making your code behavior more obvious.
> - It is easy to switch between using shortcut ModelSerializer classes and using explicit Serializer classes. Any validation behavior being
>     used for ModelSerializer is simple to replicate.
> - **Printing the `repr` of a serializer instance will show you exactly what validation rules it applies. There's no extra hidden validation
>     behavior being called on the model instance.**
>
> When you're using ModelSerializer all of this is handled automatically
>   for you. If you want to drop down to using a Serializer classes
>   instead, then you need to define the validation rules explicitly.
>
> #### Example
>
> As an example of how REST framework uses explicit validation, we'll
>   take a simple model class that has a field with a uniqueness
>   constraint.
>
> ```
> class CustomerReportRecord(models.Model):
>     time_raised = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
>     reference = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
>     description = models.TextField()
> ```
>
> Here's a basic ModelSerializer that we can use for creating or
>   updating instances of CustomerReportRecord:
>
> ```
> class CustomerReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>     class Meta:
>         model = CustomerReportRecord
> ```
>
> If we open up the Django shell using manage.py shell we can now
>
> ```
> >>> from project.example.serializers import CustomerReportSerializer
> >>> serializer = CustomerReportSerializer()
> >>> print(repr(serializer))
> CustomerReportSerializer():
>     id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
>     time_raised = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
>     reference = CharField(max_length=20, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=CustomerReportRecord.objects.all())>])
>     description = CharField(style={'type': 'textarea'})
> ```